# Laravel store (nullable validation error)

Tags: laravel

I've currently got the following store function

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'url' => ['required', 'url'],
        'image' =>  ['nullable', 'image'],
    ]);

    $DB1 = new \App\Part1();
    $DB1->name = $data['name'];
    $DB1->save();

    $DB2 = new \App\Part2();
    $DB2->db1_id = $DB1->id;
    $DB2->description = $data['description'];
    $DB2->url = $data['url'];
    $DB2->image = $data['image'];
    $DB2->save();
}
```

Every time I've got an empty image I get the following error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined index: image
```

I thought the `nullable` rule would be enough.

The only work around I found is to check if the image is empty but it feels like I am doing it wrong:

```
if (request('image')) {
    $image = $data['image'];
} else {
    $image = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isset` or `empty` method or `??` operator

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'url' => ['required', 'url'],
        'image' =>  ['nullable', 'image'],
    ]);

    $DB1 = new \App\Part1();
    $DB1->name = $data['name'];
    $DB1->save();

    $DB2 = new \App\Part2();
    $DB2->db1_id = $DB1->id;
    $DB2->description = $data['description'];
    $DB2->url = $data['url'];
    $DB2->image = isset($data['image']) ? $data['image'] : null;
    // or $DB2->image = !empty($data['image']) ? $data['image'] : null;
    // or $DB2->image = $data['image'] ?? $data['image'];
    $DB2->save();
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

simply use the new PHP7  feature for in line checking and acting :

```
$DB2->image = $data['image']?? NULL;
```

its not about wrong or not, it is about the good and the better.

Now the `??` mean if the $data['image'] is null(false) then simply set NULL to  $DB2->image.